# How to compute median conditional on several factors in hierarchical data?

Tags: stata, descriptive-statistics

We have a database with different countries and each country is divided in a number of industries.

We want to generate a new measure for industry profitability which will be the median per industry per country.

What would the command be in Stata? We already have the measure for profitability.

Answer (score 1):

```
bysort country industry: egen mediprof = median(profitability)
```